# Video player for xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-videoview

Hello can anyone provide me good plugin or sample for video player implementation in xamarin forms?
Req: 
1) Player should have built in controller. 
2) Should be able to show the video loading symbol
3) Video should have the video image with play button.

Can anyone help me pls?

Answer (score 1):

This is the one that I use and it supports Video source from file as well as stream source. So far, this is the best I found for Xamarin forms.

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/video-player

Comment: Hello @Habeeb. Will it show video image with play button like how we see in youtube videos list? Also does it show the loading symbol in the video view while buffering?

Comment: I tried trial of this. It does not have these two features                                                    2) Should be able to show the video loading symbol 3) Video should have the video image with play button.

Comment: For Loading, you will need to use activityLoader and you can bind its visible and isRunning property to the isLoading Property of the videoplayer. Image with playbutton, I haven't tried as I play on load. But you can do workaround to simulate this behaviour.

Comment: I got the player and nowi need a cross platform technique to capture a thumbnail of the saved video.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [LibVLCSharp](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp). Official VLC bindings for Xamarin/.NET.

Samples here: https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples

Disclaimer: I am the maintainer.

Comment: There is no facility for repeat the video in this player @mfkl